# Sorting and filtering on Date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, momentjs, angularjs-filter

I have a date column and need to be able to both sort and filter on it. The data comes in as strings like `2010-12-23` and can pre-processed as needed. It should be shown as `23.12.2010`. Some internationalization will come later.

I wonder what's the proper internal representation:

- a string like `"23.12.2010"` is bad for sorting (it could be done by sorting on function result, but it'd be slow)
- a string like `"2010-12-23"` sorts correctly, can be formatted easily, but filtering for `23.12` does not work (it could be done, but it'd be slow)
- `Date` would probably get sorted correctly, but filtering would be slow
- [moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) could be the solution, no idea

My current idea is to create an object containing both milliseconds and the displayed string, so that all operations can be fast. But I'd bet that someone was that smart before me....

---

Let's assume that showing dates in the form like `2010-12-23` is unacceptable, otherwise the problem is solved. To summarize, the problem is that I need to

- display and filter in the `DD.MM.YYYY` format
- sort according to the numerical value (or equivalently, as if it was in th ISO format).

Comment: Bottom line everything gets converted to timestamps and is being naturally sorted.

Comment: Are you sure you mean `"2010-23-12"`? Probably `"2010-12-23"`, that is ISO 8601 format (yyyy-mm-dd). That'd be fast for filtering by "mm-dd" filters and also naturally sorts.

Comment: Also, why not use the built-in `date` filter to show the data in string representation, and use `orderBy: +/-date`?

Comment: @MuliYulzary Displaying with the `date` filter is fine, sorting with `orderBy`, too, but for filtering, I need the string `"23.12.2010"`, which can be done, but it takes time. Moreover, the conversion gets then done twice, once for the view and once for the filter.

Comment: What are your filtering requirements? I, personally, always do everything in YYYY-MM-DD because then everyone is on the same page.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan It must work as expected: If you see `"23.12.2010"`, then you don't expect it to disappear when filtering on `"23.12"`. +++ Yes, the ISO format is clearly the simplest, I'll ask if it's acceptable.

Comment: So you're using a text filter?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan Currently I am. There's a row allowing to specify filtering on any column or combination thereof. I guess, the users expect it to work like a text filter (I may add some options for date ranges or alike later). I'm doing the filtering myself. Ideally, it should be case-insensitive and Unicode-aware, but this may get too slow.

Comment: You can also create your own filter converting your dates to string (only when filter is applied) and then searching by the pattern of the string.

Comment: How big is the list?

Comment: @Wainage It can get really big for the admin (10k items with my testdata; the current real lists are small, but we're just starting). The displaying of huge lists is not a problem (as only a tiny part fits on the screen), but the whole list must be filtered and sorted. A part of this could do the server, but currently I'm trying client-side.

Comment: Can you handle ranges? If filter string is converted to a range BEFORE filtering and you keep data as Date then you will have both fast sorting and filtering

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I could do this, but I'm afraid, it's not the behavior user's expect. When they type in `.12.`, they expect to see all December dates (of any year). This is rather stupid and not especially useful, but that's what everyone can understand (without thinking about it).

Comment: No, of course you MAY not expose this to users (or yes, it depends) but it's what you do with Javascript. I thought about simpler expressions like 2016.12. or 2016 where range is applicable. Did you try with simple functions to perform comparison (picking right one according to filter input)? For just 10k items you should have decent performance (what's the code you are using for this?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the method you're proposing wouldn't run in to too many performance issues, unless you're going for really old browsers or mobile devices.

I've mocked up an example to do a quick (performance) test. First, I'm defining an object that holds a value optimized for sorting, and a value optimized for display:

```
var MyDate = function(dateString) {
    var date = new Date(dateString);
    var displayValue = "{0}.{1}.{2}"
        .replace("{0}", prefixZeroIfNeeded(date.getUTCDate()))
        .replace("{1}", prefixZeroIfNeeded(date.getUTCMonth() + 1))
        .replace("{2}", date.getUTCFullYear());

    return {
        sortKey: date.getTime(),
        displayValue: displayValue
    };
};
```

The `prefixZeroIfNeeded` method ensures we get the `DD.MM` format rather than the `dd.mm` one:

```
var prefixZeroIfNeeded = function(nr) {
    return nr < 10 ? "0" + nr : "" + nr;
};
```

Then, we need some data to convert:

```
var data = [];
var myDates = data
    .map(MyDate)
    .sort(function(date1, date2) {
        return date1.sortKey - date2.sortKey;
    });
```

Finally, a quick example of a very basic search function:

```
var searchMyDates = function(str) {
    return myDates.filter(function(myDate) {
        return myDate.displayValue.indexOf(str) !== -1;
    });
};
```

Now, we can create some mockup data and check how long it would actually take to *A)* map and sort the raw strings to the `MyDate` objects, and *B)* search for a string in our collection.

Here's how I generated the raw data:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i += 1) {
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) + 1900;
    var m = prefixZeroIfNeeded(Math.floor(Math.random() * 13));
    var d = prefixZeroIfNeeded(Math.floor(Math.random() * 29));

    data.push(y + "-" + d + "-" + m);
}
```

Using `console.time` to measure, processing the data on my machine (A) takes around 40ms. Searching for the string `.12.` takes around 5-10ms.

**Concluding:** I think you were definitely on the right track and could continue work in the proposed direction. **However**, in my personal experience, I've learned that whenever I start work on a feature that involves dates and times, `moment.js` is the way to go. You'll eventually run in to daylight saving time, time zones, you name it and regret you thought it was simple...

Let me know if this is of any help.

*Edit: the code in a snippet (check your browser console for output)*

```js
var data = [];

var prefixZeroIfNeeded = function(nr) {
  return nr < 10 ? "0" + nr : "" + nr;
};

// Generate random data:
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i += 1) {
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) + 1900;
  var m = prefixZeroIfNeeded(Math.floor(Math.random() * 13));
  var d = prefixZeroIfNeeded(Math.floor(Math.random() * 29));

  data.push(y + "-" + d + "-" + m);
}



var MyDate = function(dateString) {
  var date = new Date(dateString);
  var displayValue = "{0}.{1}.{2}"
    .replace("{0}", prefixZeroIfNeeded(date.getUTCDate()))
    .replace("{1}", prefixZeroIfNeeded(date.getUTCMonth() + 1))
    .replace("{2}", date.getUTCFullYear());

  return {
    sortKey: date.getTime(),
    displayValue: displayValue
  };
};

console.time("Map and sorting");

var myDates = data
  .map(MyDate)
  .sort(function(date1, date2) {
    return date1.sortKey - date2.sortKey;
  });

var searchMyDates = function(str) {
  return myDates.filter(function(myDate) {
    return myDate.displayValue.indexOf(str) !== -1;
  });
};

console.timeEnd("Map and sorting");

console.time("Search");

console.log("Searching for the month 12, %d results.", searchMyDates(".12.").length);


console.timeEnd("Search");
```

Comment: We decided to stick with ISO format for now, which makes things simple and fast. Currently, I'm using moment.js for formatting (though it's unnecessary now), but I'm using strings representation for dates. Things may change one day. I may have to use Moment objects and maybe extend it with `sortKey`/``displayValue` when I run into performance problems.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you a bit. I have used the same thing working with React. Here is a link for Moment.js -
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/
If you go under Display -> Format on the right menu bar, you'll see localized formats, you will need to use format L - pre defined format from moment which will show you 09/04/1986 (September 4, 1986); otherwise you can create your own using DD-MM-YYYY format.

For Example, The way I used in React for my exercise is

To define a variable using let:
`let deadlineFormated = Moment(this.props.ToDoItem.deadline).format('llll');`

Hope this helps for Angular!

Answer (score 1):

Gist: Decouple sorting and filtering. Do sorting on the internal representation and filtering on the presentation.

Sort on internal representation that is in any naturally sortable format. Your raw YYYY-MM-DD date strings would work, so would parsing them into Date objects. The performance difference could be negligible unless you're dealing with lots and lots of rows -- but in that case you would already have other issues with latency and rendering performance.

It's more intuitive if free-text filtering is done on what's displayed (the presentation). So if you're formatting the dates as "May 7, 2016", do a substring match on that. If you're formatting the dates as DD.MM.YYYY, do a substring match on that.

If filtering is driven by actual date selections from controls like a date picker or a select field, you can do the filtering on the internal representation.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:
Get Unixtimestamp for date (i.e. Numeric format) and use jquery sort.

Please check this example for jquery sort. Regarding example replace your unixtimestamp to value.

```
<ul id="datelist">
<li value="1360013296">Date 1</li>
<li value="1360013297">Date 2</li>
<li value="1360013298">Date 3</li>
<li value="1360013299">Date 4</li>
</ul>

https://jsfiddle.net/ajaygokhale/bohgoq8o/
```

Answer (score 0):

To reliably implement sorting converting it into a Date Object is recommended (**new Date(str)**)

If you need to be flexible in formatting **moment** has formatting support (check moment.format()) as well. Moment has pretty deep locale support as well.

You can always keep it a Date Object as the source of truth and for filtering you could do Date.toString() just at the time of filtering. This returns a string you could then filter with.